# Dynamically created uitextfield's screen position

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I'm developing an iphone app as a newbie. I dynamically create UItextFields like

```
for (int i = 0; i <= currentAnswerLen; i++) {
    [textField4 setTag:i];
    textField4 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((50 + (i * 40)), 180, 30, 35)];
etc.......
}
```

The question is, when i'm clicking a field keyboard appears and textfields can not be seen. Keyboard appears on them. How can I change the position of textfields when keyboard show up?

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your interface add this variable

```
@interface example : UIViewController
{
    CGFloat animatedDistance;

}
```

In your implementation class add this

```
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;
```

Then add these two delegate methods

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Then just remember to set up your textField delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Add a UIScrollView in to your Xib and make IBOutlet connection, that  add all the Labels that you are creating dynamically. 
I made some modification in your code. Its working fine.

```
-(void)setAnswerField
{
    int len = 10;
    int commonSpace = 20;
    for (int i=0;i<=len;i++)
    {
        if(i != 0)
            commonSpace += 40;
        textF=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((i * 60))+commonSpace,180,60,35)];
        [textF setTag:i];
        [textF setDelegate:self];
        [textF setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [textF setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [textF addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldFinished:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
        textF.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        [textF addTarget:self action:@selector(keyDown:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
        [_textfieldsScrollView addSubview:textF];
    }

     _textfieldsScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1000, 500);
}
```

While clicking text field textViewDidBeginEditing method fire , just change the content off set value like this.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

        [_textfieldsScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];
        [_textfieldsScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100) animated:YES];

}
```

After that revert back to original position like this.

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    //Back to normal state. 
    [_textfieldsScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: actually your answer makes sense but i guess i'm missing something; i added textfield to scrollview when dynamically creating as [editScrollView addSubview: textField]; but textfields do not appear on screen any more when app starts!

Comment: -(void)setAnswerField {
    for (int i=0;i<=len;i++) {
        [textF setTag:i];
        [textF setDelegate:self];
        [textF setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [textF addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldFinished:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
        textF=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((50 + (i * 40)),180,30,35)];
        textF.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        [textF addTarget:self action:@selector(keyDown:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
        [_textfieldsScrollView addSubview:textF];
}}

Comment: Your code need some corrections. i have updated the answer check now.